# Executing a Bash command asynchronously from a Perl script

Tags: perl, bash, asynchronous

I have to run a Bash command. But this command will take a few minutes to run.

If I execute this command normally (synchronously), my application will hang until the command is finished running.

How do I run Bash commands asynchronously from a Perl script?

Comment: See [How can I fire and forget a process in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133910/how-can-i-fire-and-forget-a-process-in-perl)

Comment: Do you care about bash output?

Comment: Yes. I want the result, what and when? something like: when the command is finished, it alert back to my application like event trigger.

Comment: Below is example with threads where you get script output, but from time to time you have to manually check if script has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `threads` to start Bash asynchronously,

```
use threads;
my $t = async {
  return scalar `.. long running command ..`;
};
```

and later manually test if thread is ready to join, and get output in a non-blocking fashion,

```
my $output = $t->is_joinable() && $t->join();
```

Comment: +1. I have a minor issue. If after `async` line `$t` is used, then perl returns an error: `Global symbol "$t" requires explicit package name`. A `sleep 1;` before the first usage of `$t` solves this problem, but is there a proper way to handle this?

Comment: ``my $t = async { return `./wait.sh`; }`` `print $t;`. If `sleep 1` is added in between the two lines then it works properly.

Comment: I've got `Perl exited with active threads:` and you don't need `sleep` to avoid this behavior, as `my $foo = $t->join();` will block until thread is ready to join.

Comment: Hmmm... `$t->join;` also does not work as the `$t` is not visible (same error message). Same under `cygwin` and `CentOS 5.7`.

Comment: @TrueY And you're sure the `$t->join` is in the scope of `$t`?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not care about the result, you can just use `system("my_bash_script &");`. It will return immediately and the script does what is needed to be done.

I have two files:

```
$ cat wait.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}; { echo "wait#$i"; sleep 1;}

$cat wait.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
my $t = time;
system("./wait.sh");
my $t1 = time;
print $t1 - $t, "\n";
system("./wait.sh &");
print time - $t1, "\n";
```

Output:

```
wait#1
wait#2
wait#3
wait#4
wait#5
5
0
wait#1
wait#2
wait#3
wait#4
wait#5
```

It can be seen that the second call returns immediately, but it keeps writing to the stdout.

If you need to communicate to the child then you need to use `fork` and redirect `STDIN` and `STDOUT` (and `STDERR`). Or you can use the [IPC::Open2](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html) or [IPC::Open3](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/IPC::Open3/) packages. Anyhow, it is always a good practice to wait for the child to exit before the caller exits.

If you want to wait for the executed processes you can try something like this in Bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

cpid=()
for exe in script1 script2 script3; do
  $exe&
  cpid[$!]="$exe";
done

while [ ${#cpid[*]} -gt 0 ]; do
  for i in ${!cpid[*]}; do
    [ ! -d /proc/$i ] && echo UNSET $i && unset cpid[$i]
  done
  echo DO SOMETHING HERE; sleep 2
done
```

This script at first launches the script# asynchronously and stores the pids in an array called `cpid`. Then there is a loop; it browses that they are still running (/proc/ exists). If one does not exist, text `UNSET <PID>` is presented and the PID is deleted from the array.

It is not bulletproof as if `DO SOMETHING HERE` part runs very long, then the same PID can be added to another process. But it works well in the average environment.

But this risk also can be reduced:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Enable job control and handle SIGCHLD
set -m
remove() {
  for i in ${!cpid[*]}; do
    [ ! -d /proc/$i ] && echo UNSET $i && unset cpid[$i] && break
  done
}
trap "remove" SIGCHLD

#Start background processes
cpid=()
for exe in "script1 arg1" "script2 arg2" "script3 arg3" ; do
  $exe&
  cpid[$!]=$exe;
done

#Non-blocking wait for background processes to stop
while [ ${#cpid[*]} -gt 0 ]; do
  echo DO SOMETHING; sleep 2
done
```

This version enables the script to receive the SIGCHLD signal when an asynchronous sub process exited. If SIGCHLD is received, it asynchronously looks for the first non-existent process. The waiting while-loop is reduced a lot.

Comment: Yet another option is `open(my $fh, '|-', 'wait.sh', ...)` or `open(my $fh, '-|', 'wait.sh', ...)` if you want to read its output or write its input but not both.

Comment: No. you don't understand me @TrueY, the bash command of me takes a lot of time to run, so i want when the bash command is executing, my app show text "Executing..." and after finishing command, system triiger (notice) my app to show "Execute done!".

Comment: @ThếAnhNguyễn: Sorry for my misunderstanding, but your description does not contain too much information. I had a [SO answer to an other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772186/bash-parallelize-md5sum-checksum-on-many-files/16773505#16773505). It runs specific number of parallel programs in bash. I tailor it for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to do this is with `fork`. You'll have your script fork, and the child would then call either `exec` or `system` on the Bash script (depending on whether the child needs to handle the return code of the Bash script, or otherwise interact with it).

Then your parent would probably want a combination of `wait` and/or a `SIGCHILD` handler.

The exact specifics of how to handle it depend a lot on your situation and exact needs.