# Bash: parallelize md5sum checksum on many files

Tags: bash

lets say, I have a 64-core server, and I need to compute `md5sum` of all files in `/mnt/data`, and store the results in a text file:

```
find /mnt/data -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > md5.txt
```

The problem with the above command is, that only one process runs at any given time. I would like to harness the full power of my 64-cores. Ideally, I would like to makes sure, that at any given time, 64 parallel `md5` processes are running (but not more than 64).

Also. I would need output from all the processes to be stored into one file.

NOTE: I am not looking for a way to compute `md5sum` of one file in parallel. I am looking for a way to compute 64 md5sums of 64 different files in parallel, as long as there are any files coming from `find`.

Comment: I'm not sure this will be good. I could imagine that the stuff becomes IO bound very soon and that using 64 processes will lead to slooow IO while having many cores be idle nevertheless.

Comment: But on the other hand, modern file systems are cached a lot in RAM, so using more than one at a time makes sense.

Comment: @Alfe: the kernel will still have to fetch the data *into* RAM, so the bottleneck remains.

Comment: I am interested in a generalized answer. If md5sum is too fast for you (cca 90MB/s) than feel free to substitute any slow algorithm (xz compression 5MB/s). It is not unrealistic to suppose, that the read speed from /mnt/data can be 500MB/s (ie, NFS share over 10Gb network, or SSD disk)

Comment: In case the data already is in the RAM (consider large servers with e.g. 96 GB of RAM), that might have already happened.

Comment: If the OP want a solution for parallel running, why someone start talking about the "wrong idea"? Maybe he simply want test the I/O-bottleneck or whatever... Simply don't understand those _knows everything better_ users... (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=knowing%20everything%20better)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`GNU parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). And you can find some more examples on how to implement it [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html).

```
find /mnt/data -type f | parallel -j 64 md5sum > md5.txt
```

Comment: I did not know GNU parallel. Thanks for mentioning it. I will have to see if it is useful in my case, though. At the moment, `time find /mnt/data -type f | parallel -j 16 md5sum > md5.txt` is about 3 time slower than normal find `time find /usr/share -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > md5.txt`.

Comment: The problem with -j 64 is that it still forks one md5sum process per file; plus the overhead of parallel itself. Try -X instead of -j 64, that worked for me. Edit the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 17):

You can use xargs as well, It might be more available than parallels on some distro.

-P controls the number of process spawned.

```
find /mnt/data -type f | xargs -L1 -P24  md5sum > /tmp/result.txt
```

Comment: The provided answer does not appear to work whenever filenames contain spaces. The correct one is the following one, also using POSIX switches: 
   " find /mnt/data -type f -print0 | xargs -L1 -P24 -0  md5 > /tmp/result.txt "

You may also want to use the option -r for md5 to reverse the output and get the checksum BEFORE the path, so that you can order by checksum and easily find duplicates.

Comment: @Braiam it still wouldn't work on filenames containing spaces. Those specifically need "-print0" and "-0" to split the output not according to whitespaces (potentially within filenames) but according to null chars.

Comment: @OlafM yeah, I was talking about the depreciated flag. I wanted to keep functionality wise the same answer. The behavior of find would have that problem before the flag was depreciated nonetheless.

Comment: Now this answer got so much attention: let's bring back the comment from another deleted answer here: "This will FAIL! writing simultaneously from many streams to one file will generate corrupted file (!). Please do not use it. I have exact problem in my case. – ******** Mar 21 '14 at 6:49"

Comment: You may find that using larger values on -L improves performance by forking fewer processes (md5sum can take multiple files on its command line).  BTW, multiple process can write to the same (local) file if they all use append-mode and a sane buffering scheme (eg line-buffered).  No idea if md5[sum] is such a process.  Alternatively write to multiple files and combine at the end.

Comment: man xargs -P: "Please  note  that  it is up to the called processes to properly manage parallel access to shared resources.  For example, if more than one of them tries to print to stdout, the ouptut will be produced in an indeterminate order (and very likely mixed up) unless the processes collaborate in some way to prevent this."

Answer (score 8):

If you want experiment try install the `md5deep`. (http://md5deep.sourceforge.net)

[Here is the manual](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/md5deep.html) where you can read:

> -jnn Controls multi-threading. By default the program will create one producer thread to scan the file system and one hashing thread per CPU
>   core. Multi-threading causes output filenames to be in
>   non-deterministic order, as files that take longer to hash will be
>   delayed while they are hashed. If a deterministic order is required,
>   specify -j0 to disable multi-threading

If this not helps, you have I/O bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

If You do not want to use additional packages You can try sg like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

max=5;
cpid=()

# Enable job control to receive SIGCHLD
set -m
remove() {
  for i in ${!cpid[*]}; do
    [ ! -d /proc/$i ] && echo UNSET $i && unset cpid[$i] && break
  done
}
trap remove SIGCHLD

for x in $(find ./ -type f -name '*.sh'); do
  some_long_process $x&
  cpid[$!]="$x";
  while [ ${#cpid[*]} -ge $max ]; do
    echo DO SOMETHING && sleep 1;
  done
done
wait
```

It first enables to receive SIGCHLD if a subprocess exits. If SIGCHLD it finds the first non-existing process and removes from `cpid` array.

In the for-loop it starts `max` number of `some_long_process` processes asynchronously. It `max` reached it polls all pids added to `cpid` array. It waits until `cpid`'s length is less then `max` and starts some more processes asynchronously.

If the list is over then it waits for all children to finish.

**ADDED**

Finally I have found a proper [make](/questions/tagged/make) solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565353/have-5-scripts-running-at-any-given-time/17566149#17566149).

Comment: Thanks for the script. Unfortunately, it does not bring any improvement. Indeed, the time is longer than with simple find. Also, most of the cores seem to be idle. I will have to experiment, if I can tweek it.

Comment: @user1968963: Maybe the `sleep 1` line could be removed. It will unnecessarily load one core. Try that way. Maybe You could improve a little bit using `find /mnt/data -type f -exec md5sum {} + > md5.txt`. Mind the trailing `+` instead of `;`! This will call `md5sum` much fewer times. (see `-exec command {} +` in [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)).