# Fire a process off and have it keep running after perl script is done

Tags: perl, process

I am using a perl script to fire off a jar that needs to stay running.  However, I want my perl process to end.  I thought this thread would solve my problems:  [How can I fire and forget a process in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133910/how-can-i-fire-and-forget-a-process-in-perl)

However, I have tried both forking and using the system(cmd &) techniques and in both my perl script stays running.

Here was my code to fork:

```
if (index($all_jars, 'myjar.jar') == -1) {
  unless(fork) {
  }
  else {
    exec("java -jar myjar.jar");
  }
}
```

Here was my code for the system(cmd &):
I wasn't sure if this meant to type cmd & my command or just my command & but both systems didn't quit the perl script until *after* the jar process died.

```
system("cmd & java -jar myjar.jar");

OR

system("java -jar myjar.jar &");
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong...  Thanks for any help or ideas you could give me.

Comment: Please describe what _"neither worked"_ means.  In general, when saying something didn't work, you must explain _exactly_ what happened (error message, wrong output, computer reduced to a puddle of molten metal and silicon...)

Comment: @JimGarrison Sorry about that, I edited the topic.  I mean that the perl script didn't die until after the jar process did.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what OS are you using?

Comment: I am currently on OEL6 but it will need to work on any Windows/Unix box

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have [a lot of experience in this domain](https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super), and I've learned that the best way to create a background process *that can outlive the parent process* depends on your operating system.

In Unix, you can ask `system` to run a job in the background or use `fork` and `exec`:

```
system("java -jar myjar.jar &");

if (fork() == 0) {
    exec("java -jar myjar.jar");
    die "exec shouldn't have returned";
}
```

Note that your logic (`unless(fork){...}else{exec(...)}`) is backwards and you are calling `exec` in the parent process.

In Windows, the best way to create a background process that runs in a separate process group is with the [`system 1, ...` hack](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlport#system):

```
system 1, "java -jar myjar.jar";
```

Check [`$^O`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#OSNAME) to see what operating system you are running under:

```
if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
    system 1, "java -jar myjar.jar";
} else {
    system "java -jar myjar.jar &";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Perl has several ways to launch *background* processes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-start-a-process-in-the-background%3F).

(Note: I typically avoid posting link-only answers, but since there are several modules and that page is likely never going away, I feel it's safer than usual).

For completeness, here's a short quote from the page:

> Several CPAN modules may be able to help, including [IPC::Open2](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open2.html) or [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html), [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IPC%3a%3aRun), [Parallel::Jobs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parallel%3a%3aJobs), [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager), [POE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POE), [Proc::Background](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Proc%3a%3aBackground), and [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aProcess).