# Ruby bidirectional string buffer

Tags: ruby, io

Does ruby have a native bidirectional string buffer class? I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
buf = Buffer.new

Thread.new do
  while true
    # do some work
    buf << result
  end

  buf.close
end

Thread.new do
  until buf.eof?
    result = buf.readline
    # do some work
  end
end
```

`StringIO` supports *either* reading or writing, but not both. If I initialize a new one and write to it, then try to read from it, I won't get anything. Is there any way to get a plain old communication stream like this that doesn't require using `mkfifo` or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045693/how-to-communicate-with-threads-in-ruby

Comment: Passing in-memory object back and forth is one thing, but I need to expose a standard Ruby stream interface on both ends with the usual read/write methods. Writing a wrapper around a queue is an option, but it seems like something that might be in the stdlib somewhere

Answer (score 7):

> StringIO supports either reading or writing, but not both.

You can read from StringIO object you've just written to, just call `rewind` on your object.

I think you're looking after [IO::pipe](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-pipe).

Comment: I'll check out `IO::pipe`. StringIO will automatically rewind when you update the underlying string, but rewinding isn't what I want, since then the read would start over after every write

Comment: Sweet, `pipe` seems to be exactly what I need!